# JavaDoc can't add custom stylesheet from src/main/resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javadoc

While executing `mvn javadoc:javadoc` i get this error:

```
An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation: Option <stylesheet/> supports only "maven" or "java" value. -> [Help 1]"
```

But i read here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/stylesheet-configuration.html that `<stylesheetfile/> could be a resource in your project directory, i.e. src/main/java, src/main/resources or src/main/javadoc`

so why i can not have in my pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
            <configuration>
              <stylesheet>src/main/resources/example.css</stylesheet>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

?

Answer (score 1):

If you like to [configure](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/stylesheet-configuration.html) a file which should be used you have to use the following configuration:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <reporting> (or <build>)
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <stylesheetfile>${basedir}/path/to/your/stylesheetfile.css</stylesheetfile>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </reporting> (or </build>)
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: But i referer to situation when my resource is in my project directory check the site for this situation http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/stylesheet-configuration.html
`Configuring Stylesheets File` second point.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo not `<stylesheet>` but `<stylesheetfile>` should be used.